# make/makes in asking sentence with "or"

Tags: questions

I'm just starting to learn English and I'd appreciate an answer to my question.

What variant is correct? And why?

1. My wife or dog make me happy
2. My wife or dog make**s** me happy

Comment: Both sound very odd. Why one or the other? I would suggest "My wife and my dog both make me happy." Also, if you are a beginner https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions would be a more suitable forum for you.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should likely be *makes* because it's more common for *or* to be used exclusively, which means that only a single thing is making the person happy at any given time. However, the exclusivity of *or* is not always observed, which makes the construction of the sentence inherently ambiguous, and impossible to address with certainty unless more context is provided.